# SQL query with comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement wherein I have 3 tables

**ContactInfo**

```
idContactinfo  FirstName  Lastname      idCOmpanyid
---------------------------------------------------
1               Blah1      Blah1            1
2               Blah2      Blah2            1
3               Blah3      Blah3            1
4               Blah4      Blah4            1
```

**ContactRole**

```
idcontactrole     IdContactRoleName      idContactInfo   
------------------------------------------------------
1                       1                     1
2                       1                     2
3                       1                     3
4                       2                     4
```

**IdContactRoleLookup**

```
idcontactRole           RoleName
----------------------------------
1                        Admin
2                        Secretary
```

I need a query that gives me a result like this

```
idcontactrolename            Contacts
--------------------------------------------------------
Admin                    Blah1,Blah1;Blah2,Blah2,Blah3,Blah3
Secretary                Blah4,Blah4
```

This is what I have till now !!

```
SELECT l.sValue
    , SUBSTRING((
                        SELECT C.sLast + ',' + C.sFirst + ';'
                        FROM contactinfo c
                        inner join contactrole crole
                        ON crole.idcontactinfo = c.idcontactinfo
                        WHERE crole.idcompany = '<<blah>>'
                        and c.idcompany = '<<blah>>'
                        FOR XML PATH('')

                    ), 1, 1000000)
FROM CONTACTROLE CR
inner join contactinfo c on 
cr.idcontactinfo = c.idcontactinfo 
inner join lookupdata l on cr.idlookuprole = l.idlookupdata
where c.idcompany = '<<blah>>'
```

Comment: Your query and your table definitions do not match?  Which are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would do somethng like this, where you use the ID of the main QUERY into your SUBQUERY

```
SELECT     
l.sValue
    , SUBSTRING((
                        SELECT C.sLast + ',' + C.sFirst + ';'
                        FROM contactinfo c
                        inner join contactrole crole
                        ON crole.idcontactinfo = c.idcontactinfo
                        WHERE c.idcompany = '<<blah>>'
AND c.idcontactrole = CR.idcontactrole
                        FOR XML PATH('')

                    ), 1, 1000000)

FROM CONTACTROLE CR
inner join lookupdata l on cr.idlookuprole = l.idlookupdata
```

This will give you all the role for one Compagnie.  If the role does'nt exist you will have a NULL value.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
     RoleName,
     STUFF(
         (
            SELECT  ';' + b.FirstName + ', ' + b.LastName
            FROM    ContactRole a
            INNER JOIN ContactInfo b
                  ON a.idContactInfo = b.idContactinfo
            WHERE   a.IdContactRoleName = r.idcontactRole
            FOR XML PATH (''))
            , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
FROM  IdContactRoleLookup r
GROUP BY idcontactRole, RoleName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7c7f/10)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to get the result:

```
select distinct l.RoleName,
  left(list, len(list) -1) list
FROM CONTACTROLE CR
inner join IdContactRoleLookup l 
  on cr.IdContactRoleName = l.idcontactRole
cross apply
(
  select C1.Lastname + ',' + C1.FirstName + ';'
  from CONTACTROLE CR1
  inner join contactinfo c1
    on cr1.idContactInfo = c1.idContactinfo
  where cr.IdContactRoleName = cr1.IdContactRoleName
  FOR XML PATH('')
) t2 (list)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c85e0/32)